# How "Mean free passage time" depend on the temperature?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, diffusion, stochastic-processes

The mean free passage time in the Kramer's potential escape problem is given by
$$
\tau_{MFPT} = \frac{2\pi \gamma} {\omega_{min} \omega_{max}} exp^{\beta({U_{max} - U_{min}})} = \frac{2\pi \gamma} {\omega_{min} \omega_{max}} exp^{\beta U^{*}}
$$
The absorbing barrier is maximum as $ U_{max} $ and minimum at $ U_{min} $. How to interpret of the mean free passage time in the following three conditions: \

1. $ \beta U^{*} \rightarrow 0 $
2. $ \beta U^{*} \rightarrow + \infty $
3. $ \beta U^{*} \rightarrow - \infty $